# WCF service is deadlocking

Tags: .net, wcf, callback, deadlock

Below, I have outlined my WCF service/client setup. When a single client calls IWCFService.Process multiple times in succession the service deadlocks between WCFService.Process and the line in WCFService.Run that executes this.Subscribers.ProcessingCompleted.

An instance of the class WCFService is passed into the ServiceHost constructor and WCFService's Run API is called back from a thread created using QueueUserWorkItem. I am guessing the conflict originates between the thread WCF uses to call into WCFService.Process and the thread WCFService.Run is running under.

I have already added a ServiceThrottlingBehavior to allow 1000 MaxConcurrentSessions and 1000 MaxConcurrentCalls. Can I add attributes on the service or client classes that will prevent this deadlock?

```
[ServiceContract(Name = "IWCFClient")]
public interface IWCFClient
{
  [OperationContract]
  void ProcessingCompleted(Guid guid);
}

[ServiceContract(Name = "IWCFService", CallbackContract = typeof(IWCFClient))]
public interface IWCFService
{
  [OperationContract]
  Guid Process(string filename);
}

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
class WCFService : IWCFService, WFGenericThread<WFProcessingResult>, 
{
  public Dictionary<Guid, IWCFClient> Subscribers { get; set; }
  public override void Run(WFProcessingResult queueobj)
  {
    if(this.Subscribers.ContainsKey(queueobj.Guid))
      this.Subscribers.ProcessingCompleted(queueobj.Guid);
  }

  public Guid Process(string filename)
  {
    Subscribers.Add(guid, (IWCFClient)OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IWCFClient>());
    // send filename off to be processed
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server is not thread safe.

The `InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single` means WCF is properly preventing multi-threaded access, but your use of the thread pool behind the scenes is not subject to the same restrictions.

You need to make your server thread-safe or don't use the thread pool.

Here's a good [introductory article on multi-threading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163744.aspx).

Comment: I attempted using the following attribute on Run and Process assuming it wraps each method in a lock(this) but it also did not work.   [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]

Comment: You're not going to find any attributes that can rectify this as the problem arises from your use of the thread pool.

Comment: If I insert a lock(this) at the top of Run and Process it still deadlocks. I am not sure it is just my use of the thread pool that is at issue here.

Comment: In that case make the call without using the thread pool and see if you still have the problem.

Comment: Though you are correct about the thread safety of my code above the real problem was on the client side. The developer created a Windows Forms app and was calling the service proxy on the apps thread which deadlocked when the service called the clients callback. Thanks for the insights.